# Regular expressions - match building name

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I have links like this:

- http://cdn.guerretribale.fr/8.17/19077/graphic/buildings/mid/main2.png?e3ea3
- http://cdn.guerretribale.fr/8.17/19077/graphic/buildings/mid/barracks1.png?691e9

I want to get the file names, which in the links above are:

- *[...]mid/**main**2.png?e3ea3*
- *[...]mid/**barracks**1.png?691e9*

I have tried the following, but it does not work:
([A-z]+)[0-1]+.png

Regular expressions aren't my "strongs points".

Thank you for your help,
Bartek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
([a-zA-Z]+)[0-9].png
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/WIF9Q_26HXTvvzlA)

Comment: It gives me only the last letter of the building name.

Comment: I think the `+` sign needs to be inside the brackets.

Comment: It works very well on my website (but not on http://regex.larsolavtorvik.com/), thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to capture the name with the number, try this:

```
([A-Za-z]+[0-9])\.png
```

Comment: Yes, something like that but without the number.

Answer (score 0):

([a-zA-Z]+)[0-9]+.png

You need to escape the ., your range was incorrect, and you likely need more than 0-1 since one of your strings include "2"